# Fit 3 different images inside 3 divs with same class name

Tags: html, css

How can I fit 3 different images inside my 3 different divs with same class name?

Html

```
<div class="project">
<div class="projects" ></div>
<div class="projects"></div>
<div class="projects"></div>
</div>
```

Css

```
.projects {

    background-color:#ffffff;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    margin-left:25px;
    margin-top:60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display:inline-block;
}

.project {
    text-align: center;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0tt7qkur/)

Answer (score 0):

As you use a background-image, you can use the `background-size` property on the `.projects` selector.

It will make all the background images to have the same height and width.

You'll find usefull examples here : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: I need it to be 3 different images

Comment: The best way to do that (but that's not reflected in your fiddle) is to put different ids and/or classes for each of your list item. Then, you could use the class or id selector and the background-image property to assign the right one. If you can't do that, there is the nth-child selector that will do the job : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: Solved it. Just gave all 3 different ids.

Comment: Glad that answer help.